# Output File Is Longer?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to be able to concatenate all files within a folder and write the lines into an output file 'output.txt'. When I use the code I wrote I end up with more lines than if I use 'copy' in cmd. This code will be part of a program with multiple options of how to parse the 'output.txt' once it is more developed. The problem is that the output from this code doesn't get the same results when parsed.

I have parsed the output file using the same code against the file produced by my code as well as against an output file using cmd 'copy' function to concatenate all the files within the folder.

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob("app.*.log"):
    for file in users:
        continue
    else:
        users.append(file)


with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for fname in users:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

I end up with approximately 1100 lines longer of a file using my code versus 'copy' in cmd

Comment: 'users' is a list defined at the beginning of the overall program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most functions you don't have to overwork what you need to achieve.

```
for file in glob.glob("app.*.log"):
    for file in users:
        continue
    else:
        users.append(file)
```

Can be written

```
files = []
files = glob.glob('./app.*.log')
```

Then you could

Append all files to a list and print the list to a file

```
for filename in files:
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines.append(f.read())
```

Write out the read in per file

```
o = open('output.txt', 'w')

for filename in files:
    with open(filename) as f:
        o.write(f.read())
```

I would hazard a guess that your problem relates to your two for loops to gather filenames which is excessive.

You could change the call to

```
for file in glob.glob("app.*.log"):
    users.append(file)
```

I would also declare the variables if they are used outside the function.